# jest redux shallow не работает с компонентами, обернутыми в коннект

Tags: reactjs, redux, jest

Прошу помощи, пытаюсь настроить тестирование, обычные компоненты тестируются , а обернутые в коннект нет.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

```
  130 |         submitted: true
  131 |     });
> 132 |     const wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage store={store} />);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

Экспротируем класс при объявлении

```
export class LoginPage extends Component {...}
```

Затем в файле с тестами импортируем сам компонент без обертки:

```
import {LoginPage} from '/path/to/component';
```